# Importing a file to a 2d array in java

Tags: java, file, import, multidimensional-array

I am trying to import items from a file and put it in 3 different arrays and I am getting some errors. Here is the code I have so far:

```
package project1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Project1 {

 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    fillArray();

}

public static void fillArray() throws IOException {
    Scanner teamList = new Scanner(new File("baseball_teams.txt"));
    String[] teamName = new String[35];
    int[] teamRank = new int[35];
    double[] teamWinPercentage = new double[35];
    int i = 0;
    while (teamList.hasNext()) {
        teamRank[i] = teamList.nextInt();
        teamName[i] = teamList.next();
        teamWinPercentage[i] = teamList.nextDouble();
        i++;
    }
}

}
```

I am getting this error when I try to run the program:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at project1.Project1.fillArray(Project1.java:36)
at project1.Project1.main(Project1.java:23)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here's the contents of the file:

```
1   

Boston

0.605

2 

St.Louis

0.596   

3

Oakland

0.587 

4 

Atlanta

0.584 

5 

Pittsburgh

0.577 

6 

Detroit

0.567 

7 

Cleveland

0.564 

8 

Dodgers

0.564 

9 

Tampa Bay

0.559 

10 

Texas

0.558 

11 

Cincinnati

0.552 

12

Washington

0.531 

13 

Kansas City

0.531 

14 

Baltimore

0.525 

15 

Yankees

0.525 

16 

Arizona

0.500 

17 

Angels

0.481 

18 

San Diego

0.469 

19  

Giants

0.469  

20   

Mets    

0.457 

21   

Colorado 

0.457

22   

Milwaukee

0.457 

23   

Toronto 

0.457 

24   

Philadelphia 

0.451 

25   

Seattle 

0.438    

26   

Minnesota

0.407  

27   

Cubs    

0.407 

28   

Sox     

0.389  29    

Miami   

0.383 

30   

Houston 

0.315
```

I would appreciate any tips!

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your file content as well? It seems you have something wrong in the file. Check [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read in a double when the file contains something else. Have you tried debugging your code or just adding print statements to figure out what it's trying to read in?

Comment: @user3052882 can you show us the content of your file

Comment: Updated the question with the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are making two calls to .next*() (.next() and .nextInt()) even though in your loop condition you are only checking for one next.

If I'm correct in assuming your file looks like

```
1 teamName1 100.0
2 teamName2 43.3
3 teamName3 43.6
4 teamName4 34.4
5 teamName5 23.2
.
.
.
```

if so then maybe try reading a line at a time

```
int i = 0;
String[] ln = null;
while(teamList.hasNext()){
    ln = String.split(teamList.nextLine()); // default is split on ' ' character
    teamRank[i] = Integer.valueOf(ln[0]);
    teamName[i] = ln[1];
    teamWinPercentage[i] = Double.valueOf(ln[2]);
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: By default Scanner delimiter matches whitespace. So you can do subsequent .next*() calls if you know the order they are coming through.

Answer (score 1):

InputMismatchException exception in your code as there is data in the file which is not parsable, It is clear in stacktrace as looks to me that you are trying to invoke Scanner.nextDouble(), so your data in the file is something other then Default at the time of this invokation, make sure

you can see the stacktrace it clear shows the line at which this exception comes to you

```
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and should work. I believe this is a Locale issue. By default it would take Locale.getDefault() to parse the doubles and I believe it is not the case for your computers locale. If the format is not with "."s in your locale it will fail. You can fix it by doing

```
teamList.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with the code and got it to work by making these changes:

```
package project1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Jimmy
 */
public class Project1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] teamName = new String[35];
        int[] teamRank = new int[35];
        double[] teamWinPercentage = new double[35];
        fillArray(teamName, teamRank, teamWinPercentage);

    }

    public static void fillArray(String[] teamName, int[] teamRank,
            double[] teamWinPercentage) throws IOException {
        Scanner teamList = new Scanner(new File("baseball_teams.txt"));

        int i = 0;
        while (teamList.hasNext()) {
            teamRank[i] = teamList.nextInt();
            teamList.nextLine();
            teamName[i] = teamList.nextLine();
            teamWinPercentage[i] = teamList.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Not sure what I did exactly to fix it, but I believe it had something to do with the code I had before not moving to the next line.

Thanks again for the answers!